# How to overwrite validation in Django Rest Framework Serializer?

Tags: python, django, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework I've got a Serializer. I receive some data, of which one called `categories` is an array of strings:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 25,
    "categories": ["ADC", "HJD", "RTP"]
}
```

I want to serialize the array into a comma separated string (`"ADC,HJD,RTP"`) so that I can put it in a `CharField`.

So I created a `validate_categories()` method in my Serializer as follows:

```
class DeviceSerializer(HALSerializer):
    # here some other stuff
    categories = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = (
            '_links',
            'id',
            'name',
            'age',
            'categories',
        )

    def get_categories(self, obj):
        if obj.categories is None:
            return []
        return [
            obj.categories.choices[key.upper()]
            for key in obj.categories
        ]

    def validate_categories(self, categories):
        print("IN THE VALIDATOR")  # WE NEVER REACH THIS POINT
        print(categories)
        return categories

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # here some custom creation code
        device = Device.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return device
```

When I post the JSON the object is created but the validator never gets called.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`serializers.SerializerMethodField()` is read-only field, so it won't be used for deserialization.

You can add a new `write_only` field which will only be used for deserialization e.g. `categories_list`:

```
class DeviceSerializer(HALSerializer):
    categories = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    categories_list = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(), write_only=True)
```

Switch the field names if you don't have control over input. And add `categories_list` to `DeviceSerializer.Meta.fields` and change the `validate_` method name for the deserialization field accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't tested your suggestion yet, but I already have a question; isn't there a Field in `serializers` which is read and write? That way I don't need to use two different fields.

Comment: @kramer65 Most of the fields are. If you want a single field, you need a nested serializer or a something like a `*RelatedField` (based on your example `StringRelatedField` seems appropriate), but then we need to see your model definitions, and a detailed idea of your plan.